Auto populating radio from two text (number) field on REDCap
Please I am trying to autopopulate a radio field var1 (Yes, No) from two text field (age[numeric] and BMI[numeric)] on redcap.
kindly help me with useful options, I'm struggling with it.
what i'm trying to do is to let the radio field (var1) to display 'yes' if age>2 and BMI>15
Thanks
@CALCTEXT and @SHOWCHOICE didnt work
Although I use REDCap 14.0.15 · PHP 8.1.20 (Linux/Unix OS) · MySQL 5.7.12

You can try a combination of @IF and @SETVALUE action tags. Set the action tags of [var1], assuming the variable is of the Yes/No data type so that '1'='Yes' and '0'='No', as follows:
@IF(
    [age] > 2 AND [BMI] > 15,
    @SETVALUE='1',
    @SETVALUE='0'
)

This sets the value to "Yes" if the patient's age is more than 2 and their BMI is more than 15; otherwise, it sets this value to "No".
An important caveat is that @SETVALUE does not update in real-time; rather, it updates whenever the page is loaded for the first time or reloaded. Depending on whether [age] and [BMI] are in the same instrument as [var1], you will need to select the "Save and Stay" option on the data entry form for this field to update. If they are in separate instruments, this should not be an issue.
Alternatively, if you'd like this value to update in real-time, you will have to change [var1] to a calculated field instead of a Yes/No question. Then set the logic similarly, e.g., if([age] > 2 AND [BMI] > 15, 1, 0) where '1' represents "Yes" and '0' represents "No". The downside, of course, is that you will no longer have the labels of "Yes" and "No" for a human reader, but most statistical software programs only care about 1's and 0's anyway. Hope this helps!
